# How to convert QVariant to native QtScriptValue (Number, String etc.)

Tags: c++, qt, validation, qtscript

I had some problem with validating values in my QtScript script. The validator function looked like this:

```
function isValueInvalid(value) {
    return typeof value=="undefined" || value == null || value == "" || value == "X";
}
```

The string `"X"` is also invalid value in my setting. The values are added to some object like this:

```
someQtscriptValue.setProperty(name, myQtScriptEngine.newVariant(someQVariant));
```

Now the thing is that values which convert to `"undefined"` as string were constantly passing the `typeof` check. So I added test debug output. I printed the whole `someQtscriptValue` in the script:

```
// This is qtscript code:
print("Validating row "+JSON.stringify(someQtscriptValue));
```

And the result is confusing (shortened, it looked all the same):

```
Validating row {"SJZ_A":{},"SJZ_B":{},"SJZ_C":{},"SJZ_D":{},"SJZ_E":{}}
```

I also decided to print some info about each value:

```
var propName = "name of one of the properties";
var isValid = !isValueInvalidCEPS(someQtscriptValue[propName]);
print("someQtscriptValue[\""+propName+"\"] = "+someQtscriptValue[propName]+"  ("+(isValid?"valid":"invalid")+") type="+(typeof someQtscriptValue[propName]));
```

And this is even more surprising:

```
someQtscriptValue["name1"] = ULSE  (valid) type=object
someQtscriptValue["name2"] = 22  (valid) type=object
someQtscriptValue["name3"] = undefined  (valid) type=object
```

So apparently, if I make `QScriptValue` from `QVariant` it behaves like an object, since all values including the "undefined" one had type as object.

So what is the correct way to create QScript values from QVariants?

Answer (score 1):

So, as far as QVariants are concerned, this method works just fine:

[`QScriptEngine::toScriptValue`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qscriptengine.html#toScriptValue)

QVariant can be passed to it. If the `QVariant` is invalid, it will end up as an `undefined` QTscript value. Numeric qvariants turn as numbers and strings as strings.